# How to format data and write javascript code for displaying a dual-y google column chart

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I am pulling data from a database via PHP for several different charts using google charts. One of the charts is a column chart with dual y charts with once bar showing previous year data and one showing current year data. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to get the data into a format that can be used.

How do I get the data in format that it will display as a dual-Y chart and how do I display it?

```
<?php
//Mock-up of PHP Code
//Single Column Chart - Works perfectly
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'period','label' => 'period','type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'cases','label' => 'cases','type' => 'number');

$data_from_db = $db_object->getData();

foreach($data_from_db as $key => $value){
    $data['rows'][]['c'] = array(array('v' => $key),array('v' => $value));
}

//My attempt at Dual-Y Data
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'cytd','label' => 'cytd','type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'lbs','label' => 'lbs','type' => 'number');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'pytd','label' => 'pytd','type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'lbs','label' => 'lbs','type' => 'number');

$data_from_db = $db_object->getData();

foreach($data_from_db as $key => $value){
    $data['rows'][]['c'] = array(array('v' => $value['Category']),array('v' => $value['previous_year'],'v1' => $value['current_year']));
}
```

The data is formatted in PHP

```
//Javascript
function insert_graph(graph_data_type,location,title,type,horizontal_axis,vertical_axis)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'getData.php?id='+id+'&graph='+graph_type,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response){
            if(response === 'error'){
                //error handling
            }else if(null === response){
                //error handling
            }else{
                chart_data = response;

                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
                    drawGoogleGraph(response,location,title,type,horizontal_axis,vertical_axis);
                });

            }
        }
    });
}

function drawGoogleGraph(chart_data,chart_location,chart_title,chart_type,horizontal_axis,vertical_axis)
{
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(chart_data);

    switch(chart_type){
        case 'column':
            var options = {
                title:chart_title,
                height: 250,
                hAxis:horizontal_axis,
                vAxis:vertical_axis
            },
            chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($('#'+chart_location)[0]);

            break;
    }

    chart.draw(data,options);
}
```

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#dual-y-charts) -- just with columns instead of lines?

Comment: yes and the documentation does have Dual-y Column Charts I just seem to be doing something terribly wrong

Answer (score 0):

looks you're providing both `cytd` and `pytd` as the "dates" to plot against.

by default, you can only have one *domain* column
`chartA` plots by month with columns for current and prior year

if you want to provide multiple *domain* columns, you'll need to explicitly assign the roles -- `chartB`

examples aren't great but should get the point across

`chartB` example was pulled from the description of the [*domain* column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available)

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var dataA = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataA.addColumn('string', 'Month');
  dataA.addColumn('number', 'Current Year');
  dataA.addColumn('number', 'Prior Year');
  dataA.addRow(['Jan',   1,  13]);
  dataA.addRow(['Feb', 200, 142]);
  dataA.addRow(['Mar',  32, 149]);
  dataA.addRow(['Apr', 378, 286]);
  dataA.addRow(['May', 200, 176]);
  dataA.addRow(['Jun',  20,  44]);
  dataA.addRow(['Jul', 503, 402]);
  dataA.addRow(['Aug', 380, 204]);
  dataA.addRow(['Sep', 705, 694]);
  dataA.addRow(['Oct', 965, 445]);
  dataA.addRow(['Nov', 236, 646]);
  dataA.addRow(['Dec', 405, 547]);

  var dataB = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataB.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'domain'}, '2009 Quarter');
  dataB.addColumn('number', '2009 Sales');
  dataB.addColumn('number', '2009 Expenses');
  dataB.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'domain'}, '2008 Quarter');
  dataB.addColumn('number', '2008 Sales');
  dataB.addColumn('number', '2008 Expenses');
  dataB.addRows([
    ['Q1 \'09', 1000, 400, 'Q1 \'08', 800, 300],
    ['Q2 \'09', 1170, 460, 'Q2 \'08', 750, 400],
    ['Q3 \'09', 660, 1120, 'Q3 \'08', 700, 540],
    ['Q4 \'09', 1030, 540, 'Q4 \'08', 820, 620]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      width: '80%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: 'MMM'
    },
    legend: 'none',
    series: {
      0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
      1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {title: 'Current Year'},
      1: {title: 'Prior Year'}
    }
  };

  var chartA = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_divA',
    dataTable: dataA,
    options: options
  });
  chartA.draw();

  var chartB = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_divB',
    dataTable: dataB,
    options: options
  });
  chartB.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_divA"></div>
<div id="chart_divB"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did get the data formatted properly. The proper format was:

```
$data_from_db = $customer_profile_obj->getData();

$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'category','label' => 'Category','type' => 'string');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'previous','label' => 'Previous','type' => 'number');
$data['cols'][] = array('id' => 'current','label' => 'Current','type' => 'number');

foreach($data_from_db as $key => $value){
    $data['rows'][]['c'] = array(array('v'=>$value['product']),array('v' => $value['pytd']),array('v' => $value['cytd']));
}
```